how to implement Tracking flutter app installation?
we need to track our mobile app
for example :
first user share the app with second user via WhatsApp
now when second user installed the app and opens it
we need to send to our api server that he installed it via WhatsApp and google play or app store
I'm still searching for it

Deliver a very slightly different APK for each platform, which all sends a different message to the API once opened

There are quite a few ways to do it

Use deep linking (flutter_branch_sdk, uni_links2) for your app to handle these custom referral links.

Use plugin like package_info_plus to get information about where the app was installed.

Add app analytics like firebase, adjust_sdk, kochava_tracker etc.


Check pub.dev for more packages and versions

I tried this but I can't
is there any example ?

Check this out for Google PlayStore
https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer
Wrapper for this for flutter can be found at
https://pub.dev/packages/android_play_install_referrer
You can send link for playstore app via WhatsApp or any other medium, where each medium has unique referral code assigned

example please  as I got just the market name
